# zklib unable to get data from fingerprint attendance machine

Tags: python-2.7, fingerprint, biometrics

I have tried zklib to get data from fingerprint attendance device, but it pulls only 256 records where i have more than 1000 records in the device, how to get all the data. please find my code below

```
from zklib import zklib, zkconst

zk = zklib.ZKLib(machine_ip, port)
conn = zk.connect()
zk.enableDevice()
data_user = zk.getUser()
print data_user
```

Also i need to know, How to get daily data from Fingerprint attendance machine? please someone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

zk library provides the way to download all the logs by creating an internal buffer. You may need read by iterating the buffer one by one till you get the complete logs from the buffer. There is no option for pulling attendance records to the specific period. You need to pull all and filter internally in your logic.